# How can I change System.Text.Encoding.Default?

Tags: c#, .net

When I call :

```
oStreamReader = new StreamReader(_sFileName, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

I don't get characters with accent (by the way I expect french characters with accent).

When I display the System.Text.Encoding.Default, I get :

```
{System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding}
[System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding]: {System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding}
BodyName: "iso-8859-1"
CodePage: 1252
DecoderFallback: {System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback}
EncoderFallback: {System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback}
EncodingName: "Europe de l'Ouest (Windows)"
HeaderName: "Windows-1252"
IsBrowserDisplay: true
IsBrowserSave: true
IsMailNewsDisplay: true
IsMailNewsSave: true
IsReadOnly: true
IsSingleByte: true
WebName: "Windows-1252"
WindowsCodePage: 1252
```

Does it not expect to be UTF-8 ?

Where can I set System.Text.Encoding.Default ?

Is it bound with Windows settings ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Eric.

Comment: You know those type warts (`o`, `_s`, etc) are no longer considered good practice, right?

Comment: Remove `Default`. By default, [StreamReader](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,133) uses UTF8.

Answer (score 4):

> Does it not expect to be UTF-8 ?

On .NET Framework, it's your configured Windows code page. On .NET Core, it is UTF-8.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> In .NET Framework on the Windows desktop, the Default property always gets the system's active code page and creates a Encoding object that corresponds to it. The active code page may be an ANSI code page, which includes the ASCII character set along with additional characters that vary by code page. Because all Default encodings based on ANSI code pages lose data, consider using the Encoding.UTF8 encoding instead. UTF-8 is often identical in the U+00 to U+7F range, but can encode characters outside the ASCII range without loss

> Where can I set System.Text.Encoding.Default ?

It's your configured Windows code page.

> Is it bound with Windows settings ?

Yep

---

> ```
> oStreamReader = new StreamReader(_sFileName, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
> ```

The easiest thing is to just do:

```
oStreamReader = new StreamReader(_sFileName);
```

`StreamReader` will try to detect the encoding used from the byte order marks, but will fall back to UTF-8 if that fails, so just let it do that.

There should be almost no need to ever type `Encoding.Default` in your code: it's a badly-named property which should be ignored.

Comment: If you know you want a specific encoding like UTF-8, you can also specify that encoding: `oStreamReader = new StreamReader(_sFileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn there's no need for this, UTF8 is the default.

Comment: Well, for me StreamReader does not correctly find out what file encoding is.

Comment: @Hrvoje If there's no byte order mark, it won't have much to go on. It sounds like you have a different problem: maybe open a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Different computers can use different encodings as the default, and the default encoding can change on a single computer. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-5.0 for details. This page clearly explains how System.Text.Encoding should be used.

I would not suggest changing default encoding because the encoding returned by the Default property uses best-fit fallback to map unsupported characters to characters supported by the code page. Rather, use the encoding required by your specific code.

```
oStreamReader = new StreamReader(_sFileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: `UTF8` is [the default encoding used by StreamReader](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,133), there's no need to specify it explicitly